# Adding more than one list filter web part on a SharePoint-Site

Tags: list, web-part, filter

My aim is to add a second `list filter WebPart` to a SharePoint Site.
When I am trying to embed it to the Site, it appears like shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Is there any way, how I can make it visible, at least for editing? Or is it generally not possible, to add more than one list filter web parts on one SharePoint Page?

I've noticed it is generally a problem to add two filter Web Parts to a SharePoint Site.

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: you can add more than one filter webpart on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay somehow the solution for this problem was pretty simple. One just has to click into the "empty box" -> "Web Part properties" appear in the top tool bar. When one is editing these properties, the Web Part automatically appears after saving it.